# Global Variables for Javascript (Acrobat Reader)

Tags: javascript, global-variables, acrobat

I have a PDF form and I'm trying to declare a global variable in the Document-level Javascript editor... I'm using

```
global.myVariable = "0";
```

and then on a field in the form, I'm running the code:

```
if(myVariable == "0"){

  app.alert("Hello!");

  myVariable = "1";

}
```

So that it only brings up the alert once. However, it's bringing it up every time I enter anything into any field, which is annoying. Please advise!

Answer (score 3):

You can declare a global variable anywhere by doing:

myVariable = 1;

However it's safest if you declare your variable in the top-most scope:

var myVariable = 1;

The only issue you have to remember is to make sure you don't override `myVariable` anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

if you declare the variable as global.myVariable you will need to write your if-statement as:

```
if(global.myVariable === "0"){

    app.alert("Hello!");

    global.myVariable = "1";

}
```